# What are the significance of marking the created resource directory as Resource Root or Test resource root?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, directory, automated-tests

I don’t understand what happens when I marked a directory as resource root or test resource root in IntelliJ Idea.

Like Right click on folder -> Mark Directory as -> Resources Root

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files from the resource directory will be copied to the output directory and will be available in your application classpath so that you can access them from the code using classpath and not the file path. This allows to package your app in a jar together with the resources and distribute it to the other systems.

Separating source code from the resources in the project is considered a good style.

See [Location-Independent Access to Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) for more details.